# Unit testing a method with no return value

Tags: python, unit-testing

What would be an elegant a way of unit testing a method like this ?

```
from feedgen.feed import FeedGenerator

def generate_feed(file_list):
    fg = FeedGenerator()
    for f in file_list:
        fe = fg.add_entry()
    fg.rss_str(pretty=True)
    fg.rss_file('podcast.xml')
```

Obviously the method doesn't return any value, but writes an xml file instead . Is there an elegant way of unit testing this ? Or should I look into refactoring my method to make it more unit testing friendly and assert against something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rss_file` can take either a file name or a file-like object as its argument. Rewrite `generate_feed` to accept an argument that gets passed to `rss_file`.

```
def generate_feed(file_list, fobj="podcast.xml"):
    fg = FeedGenetaror()
    for f in file_list:
        fe = fg.add_entry()
    fg.rss_str(pretty=True)
    fg.rss_file(fobj)
```

In production, you can write

```
with open("podcast.xml", "w") as f:
    generate_feed(file_list, f)
```

or simply

```
generate_feed(file_list)
```

For testing, you can use a `StringIO` object.

```
f = io.StringIO()
generate_feed(file_list, f)
```

Then you can test the contents of `f` (via `f.getvalue()`) as if it were the XML file you generated.

Answer (score 3):

The standard way of doing this would be to use `patch` and `mock` to mock the `FeedGenerator` class.

If you pass the `FeedGenerator` in as an argument, you don't need to `patch`:

```
def generate_feed(file_list: List[File], fg: FeedGenerator) -> None:
    # do stuff to fg based on file_list
```

Now your test can do:

```
file_list = [File("foo"), File("bar")]  # or whatever?
fg = MagicMock(spec=FeedGenerator)
generate_feed(file_list, fg)
assert fg.add_entry.call_count == len(file_list)
# etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You could test to see if the file is actually created, in the correct path, and delete it after that (because it's only a test) if that's applicable to you. You can even read the file to see if it's set-up properly.

You could also have that function return `True` of `False` upon success or failure in writing the file, and test for those (for example, if you know there are edge cases that SHOULD fail).

Another useful test would be to just check that the method doesn't raise an error under various conditions.